# linking items in separate enumerated lists

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I have an enumerated list of math exercises in Beamer. I also have an enumerated list of answers to the math exercises in the last frame(s) of my document.

I would like to link each question to its answer in such a way that if I remove an exercise, or reorder the exercises, the list of answers is still synchronized with the list of exercises.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this, using `expl3` to create some functions to store the questions and answers for later use. They can then be printed whenever you want.

I used an `article`-documentclass here, but I think this would work for beamer too.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_user_Q_seq
\seq_new:N \l_user_A_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\addQA}{mm}{%
  % #1: Question
  % #2: Answer
   \seq_put_right:Nn \l_user_Q_seq {#1}
   \seq_put_right:Nn \l_user_A_seq {#2}
}
\newcommand{\printQ}{%
\section*{Questions}
\begin{enumerate}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_user_Q_seq {\item ##1}
\end{enumerate}
}
\newcommand{\printA}{%
\section*{Answers}
\begin{enumerate}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_user_A_seq {\item ##1}
\end{enumerate}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\addQA{%
  How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?%
  }{%
  A woodchuck would chuck as much wood as a woodchuck would if a woodchuck could chuck wood.}
\addQA{%
  How many ducks are there on \texttt{tex.stackexchange}?
  }{%
  Input needed from experts in the field. }

\printQ
\printA

\end{document}
```